# Sharepoint 2010 Dashboard showing error when we try to connect DataSource

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

SharePoint 2010 Dashboard showing error when we try to connect Data Source.the  Error is "An Excepted Error Occurred Contact to Administrator".
Kindly help me out. I have goggled a lot but i am unable to find the answer.

Thanks In advance

Kishan Srivastava
SharePoint Consultant

Comment: What do you mean by "dashboard"? The central admin site? What data source are you trying to connect?

Comment: Actually dashboard is the BI part it's not implemented in Central Admin.. implement it on a portal used for making reports charts  & pie charts etc.. But i am unable to connect it..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many causes:

1. Make sure you are having this hotfix installed
   http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB976462/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3571
2. Make sure PPS service is running and PPS Service application is fully configured

Comment: Thanks Madhur for your reply....
Actually issues this i have install this hotfix Windows6.1-KB976462-v2-x64.msu but it shows the message "Unable to update the system"
Actually what i though problem is PPS service is running & there is Secure Store Service that is not configured but it is running i am unable to configure the unattended account because when i go in option of Secure Store Service the generate key option is disabled...So i am very close to d problem but very far from solution...If can suggest me anyway so that i can manage it out...I have to make a Decomposition tree of Dashboard